# Dynamic regular expressions in awk

Tags: bash, awk

I have text files like

**1.txt**

```
AA;00000;
BB;11111;
GG;22222;
```

**2.txt**

```
KK;WW;55555;11111;
KK;FF;ZZ;11111;
KK;RR;YY;11111;
```

I generate this **3.txt** output

```
AA;00000;
BB;11111;KK;WW;55555;FF;ZZ;RR;YY
GG;22222;
```

with this .awk script (I use it in Windows with cmd)

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f 

NR != FNR {
    exit
}
{
    printf "%s", $0
}
/^BB/ {
    o = ""
    while (getline tmp < ARGV[2]) {
        n = split (tmp,arr,";")
        for (i=1; i<=n; i++)
            if(!match($0,arr[i]) && !match(o,arr[i]))
                o=o arr[i]";"
    }
    printf "%s", o
}
{
    print ""
}
```

Usage is `awk -f script.awk 1.txt 2.txt`

Seems to be ok but consider this situation

**1.txt**

```
AA;BB;
```

**2.txt**

```
CC;DD;BB;AA;
```

now replace in this way

`AA` is replaced with `d(2)`
`BB` is replaced with `http://a.o/f/i.p?t=1`
`CC` is replaced with `Link`
`DD` with `A_x-y.7z`

script can't generate **3.txt**

```
AA;BB;CC;DD;
```

or, using replaced text it can't generate this 3.txt text output

```
   d(2);http://a.o/f/i.p?t=1;Link;A_x-y.7z;
```

You can see that duplicates fields like `AA` , `BB`  are removed from  3.txt output because script works in that way.

I suspect it has to do with the `(...)` being taken as a REGEX grouping in `match()` as the first parameter is a REGEX and by passing `$0` and o both will be treated as "Dynamic Regular Expressions* in `awk` speak

Comment: your script has a couple of issues. Ignoring the `match` problem, you will have false positives if you have a field in `2.txt` which read `11` and `111` and `1111` .... . Instead of using `match` make use of `index`. The latter works string-based and not regular expression based. And try to search for `";" arr[i] ";"` in the string `";" $0 ";" `

Comment: `while (getline tmp < ARGV[2])` would spin off into an infinite loop if getline failed. See http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline.

Comment: It's not at all obvious how you get 3.txt from 1.txt and 2.txt. I can see where the values in the 2nd row come from but can't imagine why they're in that order. That's also not the output I get when I run your script on those 2 input files (I get `BB;11111;KK;WW;55555;FF;ZZ;RR;YY` as the middle line). Please [edit] your question to clarify how to map your input to your output and make sure the output you post is the correct output given your posted sample input.

Comment: @EdMorton yes, you are right! your order is correct, I was wrong. now I edit

Comment: If you want us to test with some specific input/output then just include that in your question, don't include something else (`AA;BB;` and `CC;DD;BB;AA;`) and then directions for how we can convert that (`AA is replaced with d(2)`, etc.) to what you really want us to use.

Comment: @EdMorton if you read my question I say that "I generate 3.txt output" but problem is not my first sample example but second sample. My code works for my first example but not for second example. You provide to me an alternative code for my first example. Yes, i want to test with my second sample example

Comment: You're going to have to do a better job of explaining the mapping from your input to your output then as it's not at all obvious, and what the problem is youre asking for help with. I took a guess at the mapping you were trying to implement and thought your whole problem was that you couldn't handle input containing regexp metachars because of how you're using regexps instead of strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS=";" }
{ key = $(NF-1) }
NR == FNR {
    for (i=1; i<(NF-1); i++) {
        if ( !seen[key,$i]++ ) {
            map[key] = (key in map ? map[key] OFS : "") $i
        }
    }
    next
}
{ print $0 map[key] }
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk 2.txt 1.txt
AA;00000;
BB;11111;KK;WW;55555;FF;ZZ;RR;YY
GG;22222;
```

The above just uses literal strings in a hash lookup of array indices so it doesn't care what characters you have in your input. If you want your input to be treated as literal strings then don't use regexp functions or operators (e.g. `match()`, `~`, `sub()`) on it, just use string functions/operators (e.g. `index()`, `==`, `substr()`, `in`).

Comment: It doesn't works for my second sample example. **1**.txt has `AA;BB;` **2**.txt has `CC;DD;BB;AA;` - if you test your script you can't return `AA;BB;CC;DD;` because you return `AA;BB;`

Comment: OK, please edit your question to clarify what it is you're trying to do and what problem you're asking for help with.

Comment: I will ask another question because I think that you are misunderstanding. I accept your alternative code