# Truncation of strings after running awk script

Tags: awk

I have this code

```
BEGIN { FS=OFS=";" }
{ key = $(NF-1) }
NR == FNR {
    for (i=1; i<(NF-1); i++) {
        if ( !seen[key,$i]++ ) {
            map[key] = (key in map ? map[key] OFS : "") $i
        }
    }
    next
}
{ print $0 map[key] }
```

I use code in this way

```
awk -f tst.awk 2.txt 1.txt
```

I have two text files

**1**.txt

```
AA;BB;
```

**2**.txt

```
CC;DD;BB;AA;
```

I try to generate this **3**.txt output

```
AA;BB;CC;DD;
```

but with this script is not possible because this script return only `AA;BB;`

**logic:** The above just uses literal strings in a hash lookup of array indices so it doesn't care what characters you have in your input. However about sample output:
if in **2**.txt there are common fields also in **1**.txt.for example `BB;AA;` then you need concatenate them in a single row, i.e `AA;BB;CC;DD;` Ordering is not required, for example is not relevant if output is `BB;AA;DD;CC;`
 Only condition that is required is avoid duplicates but my script already does this

Comment: The above just uses literal strings in a hash lookup of array indices so it doesn't care what characters you have in your input. However about sample output: if in **2**.txt there are common fields also in **1**.txt.for example `BB;AA;` then you need concatenate them in a single row, i.e `AA;BB;CC;DD;` Ordering is not required, for example is not relevant if output is `BB;AA;DD;CC;` Only condition that is required is avoid duplicates but my script already does this

Comment: Both files only have a single record?

Comment: The code in this question is the answer I provided to the OPs [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64952864/1745001) which had multiple lines in each input file. FWIW I still don't understand what the OP is really trying to do as it's not clear how an answer to this question would apply to the kind of multi-line input shown in the previous question.

Comment: @EdMorton No, Ed, your script doesn't work for this example. You need to fix it

Comment: I'm not suggesting that my solution to your previous question will work for this question, I'm saying that it's not clear what you're really trying to do since the solution to this question won't work for your previous question and the solution to the previous question won't work for this question, and both solutions are incompatible with each other. You're wrong that I need to fix anything but even if I wanted to there isn't enough information on what you're trying to do to be able to do so. If you'd like help with whatever it is you're really doing then feel free to post a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try following, as per OP's comment both files have only 1 line. So using `paste` command to combine both the files and then processing its output by `awk` command.

```
paste -d';' 1.txt 2.txt | 
awk '
BEGIN{
  FS=OFS=";"
}
{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
    if(!seen[$i]++){ val=(val?val OFS:"")$i }
  }
  print val
  delete seen
  val=""
}'
```

Comment: `C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin>awk -f tst.awk 2.txt 1.txt
awk: tst.awk:1: paste -d';' 1.txt 2.txt |
awk: tst.awk:1:         ^ invalid char ''' in expression`

Comment: @TenLogx, its a tested solution, it worked fine for me. You need to first use `paste` command then use `awk -f` command something like `paste 1st.txt 2nd.txt | awk -f program.awk` etc. You need not to pass files to `awk -f` since I already passed them to `paste` command.

Comment: ok, I use `paste 1st.txt 2nd.txt | gawk -f tst.awk > "3.txt"` to get output. Can you also provide also a solution if I consider not a single record? This is a simple example https://pastebin.com/raw/QDCLERDQ - mechanism is the same but there are more of one records for both files.Thanks in advance

Comment: @TenLogx, Could you please try my edited solution once, that should work with multiple lines too, let me know how it goes?